# Amazon S3: how parallel PUTs to the same key are resolved in versioned buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

[Amazon S3 data consistency model](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/Introduction.html#ConsistencyModel) contains following note:

> Amazon S3 does not currently support object locking for concurrent updates. **If two PUT requests are simultaneously made to the same key, the request with the latest timestamp wins.** If this is an issue, you will need to build an object-locking mechanism into your application.

For my application I am considering resolving conflicts caused by *concurrent writes* by analyzing all object versions on the client side in order to assemble a single composite object, hopefully reconciling the two changes.

However, I am not able to find a definitive answer to how the part in **bold** plays out in versioned buckets.
Specifically, after reading how [Object Versioning](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectVersioning.html) works, it appears that S3 will create new object version with a unique version Id on each PUT right away, after which I assume that data replication will kick in and S3 will have to determine which of the two concurrent writes to retain.
So the questions that I have on this part are:

- Will S3 keep track of a separate version for each of the two concurrent writes for the object?
- Will I see both versions when querying list of versions for the object using API, with one of them being arbitrarily marked as current?

Answer (score 0):

I found this question while debugging our own issue caused by concurrent PUTs to the same key.  Returning to fulfill my obligations per [1].

Rapid concurrent PUTs to the same S3 key *do* sometimes collide, even with versioning enabled.  In such cases S3 will return a 503 for one of the requests (the one with the oldest timestamp, per the doc snippet you pasted above).

Here's a blob from S3's engineering team, passed onto us by our business support contact:

> While S3 supports request rates of up to 3500 REST.PUT.OBJECT requests per second to a single partition, in some rare scenarios, rapid concurrent REST.PUT.OBJECT requests to the same key may  result in a 503 response.  In such cases, further partitioning also does not help because the requests for the same key will land on the same partition. In your case, we looked at the reason your request received a 503 response and determined that it was because there was a concurrent REST.PUT.OBJECT request for the same key that our system was processing. In such cases, retrying the failed request will most likely result in success.

Your definition of *rare* may vary.  We were using 4 threads and seeing a 503 for 1.5 out of every 10 requests.

The snippet you quoted is the only reference I can find in the docs to this, and it doesn't explicitly mention 503s (which are usually rate limiting due to >3500 requests).

When the requests don't collide and return a 503, it works how you would expect (new version per request, most recent request timestamp is the most recent version).

Hopefully this post will help someone with the same issue in the future.

[1] https://xkcd.com/979/